# HelloAndroid does not show my TextView control

Tags: android

Hello stackOverflow readers,

I am hoping that this is a simple setup issue, but here it goes:

- Eclipse 3.6.0
- AVD 2.2 and 1.5 (created both and tried with both)
- XP Pro 2002 SP3

I followed the tutorial at site http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html but my custom TextView control never rendered.

I set a few breakpoints in the **public class HelloAndroid extends Activity** method and these breakpoints are never tripped.  It is as if my **android.process.acore** is never run, based on the console output.

I am tempted to remove all and reinstall the packages, but I thought I would ask the web for a little guidance first.

This is the output in the console window:

```
[2010-08-24 12:05:08 - HelloAndroid2] Android Launch!

[2010-08-24 12:05:08 - HelloAndroid2] adb is running normally.

[2010-08-24 12:05:08 - HelloAndroid2] Performing com.example.helloandroid2.HelloAndroid activity launch

[2010-08-24 12:05:08 - HelloAndroid2] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'My_avd_2_point_2'

[2010-08-24 12:05:08 - HelloAndroid2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'My_avd_2_point_2'
[2010-08-24 12:05:11 - HelloAndroid2] New emulator found: emulator-5554

[2010-08-24 12:05:11 - HelloAndroid2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

< I then kill the Android simulator here >

```
[2010-08-24 12:05:34 - HelloAndroid2] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid2.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
```

Thanks in advance for helping me understand this issue.

Comment: Irrelevant to seeing your TextView, the breakpoints won't be hit unless you set `android:debuggable='true'` in the `application` tag of your manifest.  It's something they don't cover in that tutorial and was not originally a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What is displayed in the emulator screen ? Do you get to the "unlock" screen ?
It seems you don't wait enough for the emulator to launch.

Comment: The screen displayed "A N D R O I D" in the middle of the screen.  I waited at least 30 seconds.  I also needed my 13 year old to tell me to turn on the device with the "on/off" button.  It is working now thanks

Comment: The emulator can take up to a few minutes to start up. The android screen is the boot screen. Just wait

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but waiting and using the on/off button does not work. (I have the unlock screen up.)
Oddly, a different tutorial appears to work (Simple Flashlight).

Never mind - newbie issue I guess.

I got it to work by using (the Menu button, followed by) the Launcher icon, followed by choosing my app.